# Implementing a background processing system to update/manage application updates/backup

Tags: php, background-process

I am currently working on a fairly large purely dynamic site that contains various information that needs to be expired. Previously i did not have to worry about expiration because it was handled on user login ( various checks would run to expire the logged in user data if needed ) but with our increase member base and inactivity of users the data within the db is getting old. Normally this would not be a problem but the old data affects the rest of the sites features/functionality ( point based system features implemented, team building features, etc. ) All data stored in the database has an expiration timer so all i have to do is soft-delete the data using a php script but i don't want to trigger this on page load ( i want to avoid slowing down the user page load )

What alternatives are available aside from cronjobs. I want to be able to setup and manage the background services through php so i don't have to edit/create crons every time i need something new added, etc.

Ideally i am looking for or trying to implement a system that will allow me to insert a db row with specific instructions ( queue a specific update ) and it will be handled on the backend. I want/need to have the data updated as soon as possible to avoid the issues we are running into now. This background processor will eventually handle larger more complex tasks like auto scheduling an on site event ( tournaments ), or auto generating brackets for these tournaments. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MySQL [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html), so you could initiate a SQL script which would re-run every x days:

```
CREATE EVENT `delete_old_data` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO BEGIN
    -- event body, something like delete all rows older than 5 days
END;
```

To be honest to do more complex events like generating 'site events' it looks like you should be using a cronjob. Is there any reason you cannot use this? I am sure if you explain to your hosting provider that you need a cronjob and show them the code that you will be using it for they will enable this option on your account. (most hosts should have this enabled already)

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, but none of them is perfect.

**CRONJOBS**

You've pointed that you don't want to use them. But if your main concern about cronjobs is crontab management, you may just setup one every-minute PHP cron which then may trigger different tasks with different resolutions. You can fully manage background services via PHP that way. The main disadvantage is that you cannot perform your background tasks parallely.

**GEARMAN WORKERS**

You may also use 3rd party software, like [Gearman](http://gearman.org). Gearman allow you to write so called workers (your background services), in any language you like (PHP is supported, as well as c++, java and many others). These workers behave like ansychronous functions which may be called from anywhere of your code using gearman api. You don't have to carry about the result, simply call the function and forget. It will be done in background. Also task scheduling is a built-in gearman feature.

Another software you may use is [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com) or any other message bus system.

**NATIVE PHP ASYNC FUNCTIONS**

New PHP7 will bring native php asynchronous programming. You will be able to separate your PHP script and http request handling, a bit like in node.js. Your script will be able to work all the time, doing some background stuff in any way you like and handling http requests like events in another process. This is probably the best option for you, if you may wait till the release date.

My answer covers only solutions I was using personally. Possibly there are also another ways to reach your goal, so keep searching!

Comment: I will be deploying this app to a variety of sites both clients as well as my own. So i was looking for a php alternative to implement. I dont know if all clients will have cron access and i am attempting to make this as easy as copying the files and updating simple credentials like db etc. This way i can limit the amount that i or another individuals has to make just to install. ( I have future plans to auto deploy the script as well ) at the moment i was looking into using ajax to just call a url which would search db for scheduled tasks or markers. Not sure if this is a bad approach.